# Library compilation error

Tags: library, compilation-errors

Need help for this [Tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Ethernet-Camera/). I tried to compile the code, but I'm getting compiling error.

I tried to ask on that forum too but got no answer, the error is:

```
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD\src/utility/SdFat.h:32:0,
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD\src/SD.h:20,
 Used: C:\Program from D:\FEMV3FKI7YLJVQQ\FEMV3FKI7YLJVQQ.ino:1:
 Not used: C:\Users\IBNUM
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD\src/utility/BlockDriver.h:31:10: fatal error: FatLib/BaseBlockDriver.h: No such file or directory
Multiple libraries were found for "SPI.h"
 #include "FatLib/BaseBlockDriver.h"
 Used: C:\Program
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

How can I fix this Arduino compile error?

Comment: you copied parts of the SD library to your sketch folder?

Comment: @Juraj no, i use import .Zip file in arduino IDE

Comment: @jsotola i'm sorry, i need to edit my question

Comment: delete the library from your sketches folder, which you installed with zip. it was already installed with the IDE

Comment: 1.8.9 working fine for my sketch, but 1.8.10 said compiling error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem since version 1.8.10.

With a good running sketch I don't get any message "Multiple libraries were found" (and no warnings also)

But with every small compiler error I get a whole list of "Multiple libraries were found"

My custom libraries are in a sketchbook location
D:\DATA BACKUPPED\Documenten Albert\Arduino\Sketchbook-and-user-libraries

Comment: This answer is really pointing to a really easy but hard to notice reason for getting the duplicate library messages.  Just one compile error and this message can be thrown, however it has nothing to do with the actual problem with the code.